# IE7 Compatibility Issue with Form Input / jQuery Datepicker

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-datepicker

When viewing the site I'm working on in IE7 my Reservations area (jquery ui datepicker) is broken on to separate lines.

http://www.bestwesternsandshotelvancouver.com/

I'm unsure why it's doing this, I've been searching for a fix for a while now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue using Aaron Ray's suggestions and some tweaks of my own:

> Try making the images you use for "Check In" and "Check Out"
>   (`.checktext`) `display: block` and `float: left`.
>
> I would remove the `text-align: center` (`.res-checkin`) as well. IE7 and
>   below are a little liberal with how they handle `text-align: center`.
>
> I made these changes with Firebug, and the results were the same in
>   FF. See if they fix your IE7 woes.

After doing these, I figured out eventually that I needed to modify the margin of the wrapper I had enclosed the text-field in, so thank you very much Aaron!

Answer (score 0):

Try making the images you use for "Check In" and "Check Out" (`.checktext`) `display: block` and `float: left`.

I would remove the `text-align: center` (.res-checkin) as well. IE7 and below are a little liberal with how they handle `text-align: center`.

I made these changes with Firebug, and the results were the same in FF. See if they fix your IE7 woes.

Comment: I did these changes, it did help by moving the text/date area up to the original level, but the calendar button is still a line below.
[Here's the site now.](http://bestwesternsandshotelvancouver.com)

Also, I'm testing it with IETester.. but it seems completely accurate as I had a client send me a Print Screen of the error. http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: Actually, figured out the solution thankfully. I needed to remove the margins on the wrapper I'd setup to contain the text area & image. Thank you very much!